# Easy backup/restore of installed system?

Tags: backup

Is there any easy and open source backup/restore solution for installed (after clear install) Ubuntu system, like Acronis Home backup ?

Comment: Isn't it a duplicate of this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools I don't see the difference really.

Comment: Partially yes :) However what I am asking is an analogue software for Ubuntu like the Acronis backup is for Windows systems.

Comment: Then perhaps a rephrase would be required to be able to clearly distinguish your question from the one I linked. That would also give you more accurate answer :-)

Comment: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/creating-custom-ubuntu-live-cd-with-remastersys.html
this will do, this tutorial will walk you through it all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can use remastersys for that.You can see a complete tutorial [here](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/creating-custom-ubuntu-live-cd-with-remastersys.html)

The best way is always make a seperate /home partition.See the posts below you can find a better and easy way to backup/restore your system.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=35087

http://www.debianadmin.com/backup-and-restore-your-ubuntu-system-using-sbackup.html

Comment: I am not familiar with Remastersys, but I know about huge potential of Remastersys for creating new custiomised Ubuntu installations. What I am looking for is a simple backup/restore of installed Ubuntu.

Comment: Remastersys seems [discontinued](https://alternativeto.net/software/remastersys/). Take a look to [distroshare-ubuntu-imager](https://github.com/Distroshare/distroshare-ubuntu-imager) and [pinguy-builder](https://pinguyos.com/2015/09/pinguy-builder-an-app-to-backupremix-buntu/).

Answer (score 5):

If you are talking about Acronis® True Image(TM) Home, Bear in mind that this product is not just a file backup tool it is also a disk imaging tool which means it can take a one to one snapshot of your disk.

If you want something to run from Ubuntu desktop that can Image your system then look at Partimage here; http://www.partimage.org/Main_Page,  an old tutorial here; http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/partimage
Partimage can be installed from the software center, it supports a wide variety of file systems.

This can be used in conjunction with a simple file backup system as pointed out by others here to effectively replace the Acronis product. If you want a more powerful file backup system, Backuppc may be good, see; http://backuppc.sourceforge.net/info.html#intro, this is available in the Ubuntu repositories as well.

Comment: Good point that this is not so much about general backups.  Re backuppc, I've run across a bunch of problems with it in Precise, as mentioned briefly at [software recommendation - Comparison of backup tools - Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools).

Answer (score 3):

You don't need any software on ubuntu to do  a complete system backup. The easiest and more powerful way of backing up can be found here: [Howto: Backup and restore your system!](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=35087). You can backup and restore entire system live or from a live cd. If you have a corrupted MBR then you can use [super grub2 disk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/) . Pop the super grub2 disk in, select optical drive boot, and it will show the existing OS's on your hard drive. Boot into ubuntu, and run `sudo grub-install /dev/sda`. That's it, the easiest way for restoring grub2.

Comment: thanks for this simple elegant solution, that's all (exactly) I wanted

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu sbackup (Simple Backup Suite) is a nice little piece of software to backup your system.   It's usually what we install on home computers we give to people.  You can check it out here: apt://sbackup

Edit, here is a link to community documentation about it too: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem/SimpleBackupSuite

Comment: Looks to be inactive - no updates since 2013 (as of mid 2017).

Comment: @DavidJ now days you can use Dejadup which comes preinstalled on Ubuntu, that's what I would recommend now since it's the easiest for most users.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are talking about total (partition) backup, I recommend **Clonezilla** (runs from LiveCD)

Comment: I think that Clonezilla is a good choise, yet it is not so easy to use like Acronis Backup or Norton Ghost. I would be grateful if there is any simple full system backup software, which runs from CD or USB stick.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE 05.01.2015

The link I provide in this and other instructions in step 2 does not work anymore. However, I had downloaded the Remastersys files before the website shut down and they can be installed perfectly through Ubuntu Software Center. !! I am not sure if the files are available in Ubuntu Software Center, but if you have them on your computer, they can be installed through it.

You can use Remastersys to create a backup iso of your system

This set of instructions helped me install and run successfully remastersys on Ubuntu 14.04.1 32bit and also successfully create and use a bootable flash drive with the custom iso I made.

Note: a flash drive works unless you manually made an upgrade of the kernel for some reason before.

1. Press Ctrl-Alt-T and run

sudo apt-get install plymouth-x11

2. Go to this link and download remastersys version for 32bit or 64bit system

http://www.remastersys.com/ubuntu/pool/main/r/remastersys-gui/

IMPORTANT: I downloaded version 3.0.4-1 i386 and it WORKS I checked 3.0.2- version and it doesn't work.

3. Open Programs and Updates (search in Dash or in the System's parametres)
4. In Programs and Updates, go to Other tab and press Add...
5. Copy/paste this

deb http://www.remastersys.com/ubuntu precise main

and press OK

6. Now look for two lines with "www.remastersys.com/" in the list you can find on the Other tab and make sure you check both boxes. Enter a password if you are asked to.
7. Press Ctrl-Alt-T and run

sudo -i

apt-get install remastersys-gui

8. To open remastersys-gui, you always need root priveleges. So do it in the terminal (Ctrl-Alt-T)

sudo -i

remastersys-gui