# Does "erasing 10.04 and installing 11.04" erase document from my windows installation?

Tags: 11.04, installation, dual-boot

I have a doubt regarding the installation of ubuntu 11.04 on my Thinkpad Laptop.
Currently, my laptop has dual boot namely Ubuntu 10.04 and Windows XP.

When i tried with live cd of ubuntu 11.04 for installation, i have the following option

1. Fresh installation
2. Upgrading 10.04 to 11.04 with files retained
3. Erasing 10.04 and installing 11.04 (all the previous software and documents will be erased).

If i choose option 3, will my Windows XP unaffected?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just to clarify:

[image]

The option "upgrade 10.04 to 11.04" is not like upgrading 10.04 to 11.04 via an upgrade to 10.10.. This option means that all data from your `/home` will be preserved but you will have to reinstall your idividual applications and you will also have to create your users again. User setting from these applications (including passwords in the keyring) will be preserved.

*"Upgrade from 10.04 to 11.04"* therefore is like a clean installation (i.e. *"Erase Ubuntu and reinstall"*) but without formatting your drive and without erasing `/home`.

**As with all OS upgrades it is strongly recommended to backup your data before you proceed.**

Your Windows partition(s) will only be touched and deleted by choosing *"Erase everything"*.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the software and documents that are referred are the ones on your Ubuntu installation, not your Windows one.

Nevertheless, it's always a good idea to backup your files and documents before upgrading. Preferably with [disk cloning software](https://askubuntu.com/q/19901/6969), so you can revert back if you're not satisfied.