# Xubuntu or Lubuntu on a Mac mini?

Tags: xubuntu, lubuntu, ppc

My Mac mini doesn't have sufficient hardware for Ubuntu 11.04 (specifically Unity I think), and so I have to use the classic environment, which is fine, but it seems to run slower on 11.04 (I'm upgrading now to 11.10).

However, I heard [on PowerPCFAQ](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCFAQ#Which_Macs_are_compatible_with_Ubuntu.3F) that if it runs slow I should use Xubuntu or Lubuntu.

So my question is:

- What is the best way to upgrade from Ubuntu 11.10 to Xubuntu or Lubuntu and which one would be better for a late 2005 model Mac Mini PPC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I warmly recommended either xubuntu or lubuntu, given that you are at v11.10 together with the age of your PC.

Looking at packages.ubuntu.com, no PowerPC packages are described either for the xubuntu-desktop or lubuntu-desktop metapackages.  They have been subsequently released -  details of 11.10 PowerPC packages can be found on LaunchPad.net - for example the [xubuntu-desktop package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric/powerpc/xubuntu-desktop/2.138).

Since these meta packages have been now pushed into the standard repositories you can install the xubuntu & lubuntu desktops via

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

Looking forward, it appears there will be a PowerPC ISO available for [Lubuntu](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/daily-live/current/).  At the time of writing there doesnt appear to be an equivalent xubuntu PowerPC daily build though although this may change.  Please consult the [PowerPC FAQ](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCFAQ) for more details.

If you want to give the daily build a test, remember to image your partitions first as per the `dd` answer as per the linked question.  Do remember, this is alpha quality software.

---

Linked Questions:

3. [How to make a disk image and restore from it later?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19901/how-to-make-a-disk-image-and-restore-from-it-later)

Answer (score 3):

PowerPC packages don't show up on packages.ubuntu.com because PowerPC is not an official architecture.  You should look them up on launchpad.net instead where you will find them.

There are PowerPC meta packages for xubuntu-desktop and lubuntu-desktop. There are instructions on how to install these derivatives already [in the FAQ](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCFAQ).  I know this because i wrote the thing!!!!

The FAQ gives detailed instructions on how to install lubuntu/xubuntu from the minimal CDs plus it gives you the link to [psychocats.net/ubuntu/xfce](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/xfce) so that you could 'transform' Ubuntu into Xubuntu etc

PowerPC has exactly the same packages in the repos as other architectures with the exception of chromium/chrome and a few others.

Please read the [PowerPC Known Issues page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCKnownIssues) before upgrading to 11.10 because it is a known issue to be left at a BusyBox prompt in 11.10.

Comment: ... I have tried my best reflect your comments into the answers.  Feel free to expand if required.