# Back up the whole ubuntu system or system image creation

Tags: software-recommendation, backup, data-recovery, restore

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make a disk image and restore from it later?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19901/how-to-make-a-disk-image-and-restore-from-it-later)

In windows back is very easy with Norton ghost. Run it and forget it,
What is the same type of software for backing up the Ubuntu system? I tried DUP back up but it failed to restore when I really needed it.

Can you suggest anything regarding system back up for Linux systems?

Answer (score 3):

To create an image of a disk is very easy. Let's say you want to create an image of sda in /media/my_dev_sdb:

`sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/media/my_dev_sdb/disk_sda.img`.

If it's your main disk, then it's wise to boot a live session and do it from there instead.

Answer (score 3):

You could also check out [CloneZilla](http://clonezilla.org/). You can install `cloneZilla` from the [download links](http://clonezilla.org/downloads.php) present on the main site. Excerpt from the site as to what clonezilla is mentioned below. You can also take a look at some [screenshots of the application in action](http://clonezilla.org/screenshots.php?in_path=/00_Clonezilla)

> ***What is CloneZilla?***
>
> You're probably familiar with the popular proprietary commercial
>   package [Norton Ghost®](http://www.ghost.com/). The problem with these kind of software
>   packages is that it takes a lot of time to massively clone systems to
>   many computers. You've probably also heard of Symantec's solution to
>   this problem, [Symantec Ghost Corporate Edition®](http://www.norton.com/) with
>   multicasting. Well, now there is an OpenSource clone system (OCS)
>   solution called Clonezilla with unicasting and multicasting!
>
> Clonezilla, based on [DRBL](http://drbl.sf.net/), [Partclone](http://partclone.org/) and [udpcast](http://udpcast.linux.lu/),
>   allows you to do bare metal backup and recovery. Two types of
>   Clonezilla are available, [Clonezilla live](http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live.php) and [Clonezilla SE
>   (server edition)](http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-SE.php). Clonezilla live is suitable for single machine
>   backup and restore. While Clonezilla SE is for massive deployment, it
>   can clone many (40 plus!) computers simultaneously. Clonezilla saves
>   and restores only used blocks in the harddisk. This increases the
>   clone efficiency. At the NCHC's Classroom C, Clonezilla SE was used to
>   clone 41 computers simultaneously. It took only about 10 minutes to
>   clone a 5.6 GBytes system image to all 41 computers via multicasting!

You could also take a look at this question - [How to make a disk image and restore from it later](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19901/how-to-make-a-disk-image-and-restore-from-it-later)

Answer (score 2):

Try [backintime-gnome](http://packages.ubuntu.com/backintime-gnome) [image: Install backintime-gnome].

[image: BITSCRNSHOT]
It is a a good program for making backups of individual folders or entire drives.

The project's site is here: http://backintime.le-web.org/

Answer (score 0):

You could try remastersys! It make an ISO image of your system. To install it remember add to /etc/apt/sources.list the repository:
deb http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/repository karmic/
next:
sudo apt-get install remastersys