# Ghosting Program for Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, backup

I am looking to figure out how to set up a mass backup system for a computer network (of about 25) and am looking for a ghosting program that makes an image of the entire system for backup/recovery purposes. While clonezilla would work.. you have to manually boot us the CD for it. I am looking for a program that runs INSIDE Ubuntu that sends a system image backup off to the network server at set times, then when needed could also be used to burn the clone back to the machine. Another words- automatically and the only time I have to do anything to it is when I need to burn a backup BACK to a 'crapped' machine. Any ideas?

Comment: `rsync` is by far the easiest method. And no a complete backup is not needed. Just back up the differences.

Comment: rsync is only for the ~/ directory though.. isn't it? I am looking to back up the whole system.

Comment: rsync can back up far more than that - many people use it with the likes of rsnapshot to backup systems

Comment: ahh.. I see now :) So, in theory, all I have to do is back up the root directory ( / ) and I really have a backup of the entire system. If something goes wrong, open up the LiveCD and replace the / directory with the backup?

Comment: No you use the back up server/disc to rsync the system back to a restore point (you tell rsync to restore the system to a certain date, hour, minute, second).

Comment: Clonezilla SE provides PXE boot to create/restore disk images. http://askubuntu.com/questions/110205/best-way-to-backup-a-whole-dual-boot-system/110338#110338

Answer (score 0):

How about [dd](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dd)? Probably the original "ghost" program.