# How can I create a recovery DVD of my ubuntu installation?

Tags: data-recovery

My PC will be repaired, so I have to create a recovery DVD. How can I do this?

Comment: Does it have to be a DVD? Try [Clonezilla Live][1] with an external hard drive.


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/110205/best-way-to-backup-a-whole-dual-boot-system/110338#110338

Comment: Check remastersys, it is in repositories. It creates a LiveDVD image of your running installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean that you want to back up your entire drive so that you can restore it as it was before you sent it in for repair? Or do you want an Ubuntu installation disk with your particular set-up?

**Solution #1**

To back up your entire disk, the best solution is a product called [RedoBackup](http://redobackup.org/). It is a user-friendly product, but you have to install it first. Be aware that your installation will probably **not** fit onto a DVD, and so RedoBackup will back up instead onto different media; the recommended medium is an external hard drive, or a hard drive on a different computer over the LAN. If you do not have an external hard drive, or access to another computer over your local LAN, this solution is not for you.

To install RedoBackup, first [download it](http://redobackup.org/download.php). To install to a USB stick, install UNetBootIn (if I remember correctly, it is in the Ubuntu Software Centre), and use UNetBootIn to create the USB using your downloaded RedoBackup. To burn to a CD, use the Brasero Disk Burner in Ubuntu.

As a precaution, please do your usual daily backups before you send in your computer!

To back up your hard drive, boot from the RedoBackup CD or USB (whichever one you made). Follow the instructions to back up.

To restore your computer when you get it back, book from the RedoBackup CD or USB and follow the instructions to overwrite your hard drive. Warning: This procedure **will erase everything on your hard drive** before it restores (which, presumably, is exactly what you want).

**Solution #2**

If you cannot use RedoBackup, the best solution *in my opinion* (others may disagree) is:

- As a security precaution, back up all your data (using your usual daily backup procedure).
- Create a Live CD of Ubuntu; either 12.04 if you want the LTS, or 12.10 if you want the latest.
- Back up your *entire* home folder, *including* all the hidden folders.

When you get your computer back:

- Reinstall Ubuntu from scratch (it doesn't take long).
- Restore your *entire* home folder, *including* the hidden folders.
- Install extra programs as you need them from the Ubuntu Software Centre (always quick).