# How to create disk image/clone

Tags: backup, disk-image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make a disk image and restore from it later?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19901/how-to-make-a-disk-image-and-restore-from-it-later)

I am not sure what is the difference between image and clone but I have just installed fresh system on my laptop and I would like to have a copy if it so in time when I format the disk I could easily restore the system and its settings from DVD. What could you recommend to do?