# How to create an image of an entire remote system for using on other (virtual) remote machines?

Tags: 10.04, backup, virtualization, administration, cd-image

I have ordered several virtual machines from a hosting provider, which all need exactly the same setup:

- same users
- same programs installed
- same config (except for hostname) including cron-jobs

Is it possible and save to create a tarball of my entire system, excluding `/dev`, `/proc`, `/sys` folders and the `/etc/hostname` file and just unpack it on the disk while the system is not running (using a repair mode, or a Live CD, in case of a physical server)?

What else do I have to consider?

**Edit:** Since I have no physical access to these machines, everything has to be done from the command line.

**Edit 2:** Also `/etc/network/interfaces` should not be copied.

Comment: Check out crasic's answer regarding `dd` as a possible solution: http://askubuntu.com/questions/19901/how-to-make-a-disk-image-and-restore-from-it-later

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Do I have to expect problems if I install the resulting image on a different machine than the one it was taken from? Will the `/etc/hostname` file be the only thing I will have to change then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

1. Make sure the `/etc/fstab` is still correct, based on where you put partitions and what types they are. Make sure you run `mkswap` on any swap partition. If UUIDs are used, then you'll need to update these. The `blkid` command will give you the UUIDs of all the new partitions. If labels are used, then use the `e2label` command (or equivalent command for your filesystem) to make sure that the labels match.
2. Skip these, and make sure you create empty ones at the other end: `/run` (`/var/run` on older releases), `/proc`, `/sys`, `/dev`. Check `/proc/mounts` on the old (running) system for others (there are fewer on newer releases).
3. Update `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/hosts` (which also contains the hostname).
4. Check `/etc/udev/rules.d/` for a `70-persistent-net.rules` or similarly named file that contains any NIC MAC addresses. These are usually skipped for virtual machines though, and the only harm would be that you end up with an `eth1` device instead of the usual `eth0`.
5. As you've mentioned, you should check `/etc/network/interfaces` for correctness, especially with respect to ethernet device names.
6. Re-run the bootloader installation. This is the awkward bit. It depends on how your VPS provider boots your instance. It's worth having a plan for this before you begin.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using the [CloneZilla](http://www.clonezilla.org/) application, which allows you to either backup and restore, or directly clone, over the network.

It efficiently backs up (or clones) a disk, copying only the used parts of the partitions. It also copies the MBR.

After restoring your new partition, be sure to correct the following files:

- UUID in `/etc/fstab` (if required; in my experience, CloneZilla also clones the UUID).
- The computer name in `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/hosts`.
- If appropriate, any changes to `/etc/samba/smb.conf`.