# Upgrading from 12.04 to 13.04

Tags: 12.04, 13.04

What are the easy and possible ways to upgrade the operating system from 12.04 to 13.04?
Are there  any option except booting the system with 13.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to upgrade (IMO) is using the terminal, you do it by running the command `do-release-upgrade`.

Optionally if you don't feel comfortable using the terminal you could use the **Update Manager**, to use it press Alt+F2 and type in update-manager into the command box. Update Manager should open up and tell you: New distribution release 'XX.XX' is available. Click Upgrade and follow the on-screen instructions.

I would also recommend you read [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PreciseUpgrades) brief guide and [backup your installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19901/how-to-make-a-disk-image-and-restore-from-it-later).