# Ubuntu 18.04 fails to install from USB ISO

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb

Just downloaded Ubuntu (.iso file) and put it on a USB to install it on another computer.  I am following the documentation provided here: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#3

But when I get to the boot screen and select USB, it says "No USB bootable device found."

However, the USB is inserted and the .iso file is on it too. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you have to make a bootable USB with the downloaded ISO with third party softwares like Rufus etc.

Comment: How do I do that? There was nothing mentioned in the Ubuntu tutorial

Answer (score 2):

Copying the ISO file onto the USB drive won't do anything. You need to write the ISO to the drive, using a program like Rufus. See the instructions on Ubuntu.com: [Create a bootable USB stick on Windows](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

Answer (score 1):

You can boot an ISO file located on a USB by loop mounting it with grub2, [How do I boot an ISO file from my drive using grub2 on UEFI machines?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025656/how-do-i-boot-an-iso-file-from-my-drive-using-grub2-on-uefi-machines/1026250#1026250).

It is probably easier to use a tool like UNetbootin, (Linux or Windows), https://unetbootin.github.io/ or mkusb, (Linux), https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb, to create a Live installer USB.

Either will create a bootable USB that will work with BIOS or UEFI.