# Partitioning Hard Drive and Ghosting/Copying Ubuntu OS to it

Tags: partitioning

I searched and did not find an answer.
I have a 2t drive, nothing but Ubuntu on it.
I would like to partition a 100g to ghost/copy this Ubuntu OS to it as a bootable backup copy.
I have an ISO made by PinguyBuilders, need to figure out how to burn to a disc.
I'm new to Ubuntu.
But can copy and paste very good!
Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can't have two bootable partitions. One of the OS has to manage both system to boot.

Comment: You can use clonezilla, make an image of your original OS and clone it to your new partition.

Comment: Thanks for replying.
So best thing to do would be is to buy another HD and ghost/copy this OS to it with updates to it every so often, yes?

Comment: If a true clone, it will have same UUIDs. And duplicate UUIDs are not allowed, so you cannot have drive plugged in when rebooting. You can have various images that you can use to restore system. But many of us want regular backups & imaging is not normally best alternative for regular backup. I find I can reinstall in 10 min & then restore data, so I backup /home & some settings to make it easy to restore using rsync & cron to make it regular.

Comment: @oldfred That's true, my bad. Although you can change the UUID. But if the OP wants the same system (not just the data), is there another way that cloning?

Comment: I was hoping the software copying/cloning would let me rename the clone to say Ubuntu2, that way the original os can see there is a dif.

Comment: I thought clonezilla's save file was not the clone, but have never used it. You can use dd or clone to another drive and change UUIDs, but have to reinstall grub and change fstab references to all UUIDs that are changed. So then a bootable copy, but not easy to do regularly. Often easier to just install to another drive & copy /home and settings, list of installed apps etc to new drive.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  If all you want to have is a fully restorable image of your system just:

1. Install [CloneZilla Live as a bootable ISO](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025656/how-do-i-boot-an-iso-file-from-my-drive-using-grub2-on-uefi-machines)
2. Go to the grub menu and boot CloneZilla Live
3. Use the [device-image](https://clonezilla.org/fine-print-live-doc.php?path=./clonezilla-live/doc/01_Save_disk_image/06-dev-img.doc#06-dev-img.doc) option
4. [Save](https://clonezilla.org/fine-print-live-doc.php?path=./clonezilla-live/doc/01_Save_disk_image/08-select-disk-as-img-repo.doc#08-select-disk-as-img-repo.doc) your boot disk.
5. If you ever need to restore, go to step 4 and chose `Restore` instead of `Save`.

<sub>If my assumption is incorrect, leave a comment and I'll delete my answer.</sub>