# Casper-rw Persistence Files Not Working with 20.04

Tags: usb, live-usb, usb-drive, usb-installation, persistence

I have just noticed that casper-rw **persistent files** are not working with Ubuntu 20.04 when **booted from an ISO file**.

**Persistent partitions** are again working, however persistent partitions do not work with "persistent-path" and only one persistent partition is allowed per USB drive.

This means that a multiboot, multipersistence USB drive is no longer possible using ISO files.

I have also just tested BIOS and UEFI boot modes of a Persistent UNetbootin USB drive and persistence does not seem to be working with Syslinux either.

Hopefully someone will point out where I am making an error, or show how to fix this problem.

Reference: [How do I boot an ISO file from my drive using grub2 on UEFI machines?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025656/how-do-i-boot-an-iso-file-from-my-drive-using-grub2-on-uefi-machines/1025863#1025863)

Bug Report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1877222

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### casper-rw is now writable

The persistent file/partition name in Ubuntu 20.04 has been officially changed from `casper-rw` to `writable`.

On my computer a persistent partition can be named either `casper-rw` or `writable` and it will still work.

However a persistent file must now be named `writable`.

On a persistent 20.04 drive made with Unetbootin, changing `casper-rw` to `writable` will also fix persistence.

One Live USB expert compared this to America changing the name of the dollar to "valuable".

Comment: I wonder why they renamed, casper-rw made more sense, casper system read write. -rw felt like an extension as well, while "writable" is such plain name