# How can I replace Fedora with Ubuntu without using a USB drive?

Tags: system-installation, usb

I have Fedora installed and I want to replace it with Ubuntu without using a USB drive. I want to use Ubuntu because of less software availability on Red Hat.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "*install Ubuntu on Fedora*." Do you mean replace Fedora with Ubuntu? Install them in parallel (dual-boot)? Something else?

Comment: Are you asking to replace your Fedora system with Ubuntu? You will likely need either a bootable USB or DVD in order to make this happen easily.

Comment: I want to replace fedora with ubuntu

Comment: @karel: A lot of answers there, to keep the OP busy for quite a while, only I did not see even one answer that **did not require a USB drive** as the OP asked.

Comment: @Pilot6 I highly doubt that there is another question on Ask about installing Ubuntu from Fedora without using a USB. At least I looked and could not find one. **This is Not a Duplicate**.

Answer (score 1):

### Booting ISO from GRUB Menu

The method on this page should work for booting an Ubuntu ISO from the Fedora GRUB bootloader  [20.04 booting .iso from GRUB menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1251729/20-04-booting-iso-from-grub-menu/1251782#1251782)  No need for a USB here.

**To reiterate:**

- Add the following menuentry to /etc/grub.d/40_custom:

  ```
  menuentry "isoname ISO" {
    set root=(hdX,Y)
    set isofile="/[path]/[isoname].iso"
        loopback loop $isofile
        linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile toram --
        initrd (loop)/casper/initrd
  }
  ```

Where `(hdX,Y)` is the disk and partition the ISO is on, `[path]` is the path to the folder the ISO file is in, and `[isoname]` is the name of the ISO

- In Terminal run:

  ```
  sudo update-grub
  ```
- Reboot and select Ubuntu from the grub menu. Install as usual.
- Please let us know how this works for you.

Comment: I am a begginer can you tell me in some nice way

Comment: @Vedant Nandwana: Answer has been edited. Please let us know if this works for you.