# Run Ubuntu ISO live image from Windows BIOS - no USB or DVD

Tags: boot, grub2, windows, usb-installation

How to run the Ubuntu ISO live image from Windows without USB or DVD?

---

*This is a self answered question*.

Answer (score 3):

## Run Ubuntu ISO live image from Windows BIOS - no USB or DVD

> WARNING: although I hadn't any problems, I guess that could be cases, due to some mistake or other reasons, that renders Windows and/or Ubuntu unbootable. My tests where limited.
>
> If there's access to the GRUB console, some problems may be fixed.

---

#### Downloads

- Ubuntu ISO image.
- Partition manager, I used [IM MAGIC resizer](https://filehippo.com/es/download_im-magic-partition-resizer-free/post_download/). Install.
- CD emulator, I used [WinCDemu](https://github.com/sysprogs/WinCDEmu/releases/download/v4.1/WinCDEmu-4.1.exe). Install.
- [WINGRUB](https://sourceforge.net/projects/grub4dos/files/WINGRUB/WINGRUB%200.02%20Build%206/WINGRB0206.EXE/download). Install.

---

#### Setup

1. Create a primary FAT32 partition with the partition manager, 4GB is enough. This partition will be, in linux, `/dev/sda2` because is the second partition. If you got previously more partitions, and for example the FAT created partition is the third, it will be `/dev/sda3`.

   [image]
2. Mount the ISO image with the CD emulator and copy its content on the FAT partition created.

---

#### Install GRUB with WINGRUB

Follow the steps shown in the images:

1. Select the "default" option and insert a new item:

   [image]
2. Edit the new item:

   [image]
3. Insert the code shown below:

   [image]

   Here is the code to copy:

   ```
   title Ubuntu
   root (hd0,1)
   kernel /casper/vmlinuz root=/dev/sda2 boot=casper
   initrd /casper/initrd
   ```
4. Save the created menu as `MENU.LST`:

   [image]

   [image]
5. Install GRUB.

   [image]

   > The System drive, in this cased `D`, is the Windows name of the FAT partition created. It could be other letter in your system:

   [image]

   > You won't get any message of successful installation, but it's done.
6. Reboot and enjoy.

---

Tested on Windows XP SP2, Xubuntu 18.04 i386.

Comment: I managed the same thin using Grub2Win, but your method looks a little nicer. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1290224/can-i-install-ubuntu-on-my-laptop-from-windows-10-without-a-usb-or-dvd/1290304#1290304

Comment: @C.S.Cameron I wanted to try Grub2Win, but the netbook I used didn't have the display resolution (set to the max) that the program required (?), it just threw an error.