# Can I install Ubuntu on the same partition as windows 10

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I have a 256 ssd with 40 gB free. I don’t want to partition it. Can I install Ubuntu alongside windows 10 on the same partition? If so, is there a special way to install it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install Ubuntu on a NTFS partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55441/install-ubuntu-on-a-ntfs-partition)

Comment: Maybe the Windows Subsystem for Linux.  See https://superuser.com/questions/1185033/what-is-the-home-directory-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux  Newer than that other question, forget Wubi, it's obsolete.

Comment: The correct answer to the question as asked is no. Ubuntu is an OS

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu and Windows can NOT be on the same partition. Ever.

...unless one is a Virtual Machine.

...or an image file of a system (instead of an installed system).

Comment: You can boot a Ubuntu ISO file installed on the same partition as Windows, using grub2Win, etc.

Answer (score 2):

### GRUB2 for Windows

**This is a Persistent Live install, not a Full install**

You can download the Ubuntu ISO to a folder on the Windows partition of your HDD.

You can install GRUB2 for Windows, (Grub2Win): https://sourceforge.net/projects/grub2win/files/

You can create a persistence **writable** file.

You can boot the Ubuntu ISO using GRUB2 for Windows.

**GRUB Menuentry:**

```
  menuentry "ubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso" {
     set isofile="/ubuntu-20.04.1/ubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso"
     loopback loop (hd0,1)$isofile
     linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile noprompt noeject maybe-ubiquity nopersistent
     initrd (loop)/casper/initrd
  }
```

A second method using WINGRUB can be found here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1309642/43926

Comment: +1 That's mighty clever. I had not thought of mucking with the bootloader.

Comment: @user535733 The main problem I am having testing it practically, is that for the persistence file to work on NTFS, it must be contiguous.

Comment: Maybe make a pagefile of the required size and rename it, but not sure it there are other things to make it not seen as a real pagefile -- but it should be contiguous.