# Allocating disk space to different file system

Tags: partitioning, disk

[image]

This is the partition break of my PC. Filesystem partition 2 (25GB) is the partition where my **ubuntu20.04LTS** is intalled (it is not multiple booted with any other OS). I want to allocate the 270GB free space to the filesystem partition but since it is not next to the target I cannot expand it.

Kindly assist me in this issue.

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. Please edit the question or add a flag. What version is it? It is possible the version affects the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a live environment to do this, as provided by the Ubuntu installation media.

1. Backup any data you cannot afford to lose
2. Using your Ubuntu install media boot into a live environment (Try Ubuntu not install Ubuntu)
3. Using GParted move the small 499MB FAT partition all the way to the left, next to the NTFS partition. Apply the change. That will move the unused space next to your 25GB Ubuntu partition
4. Using GParted resize your Ubuntu partition and apply the change.
5. That’s it, reboot and you should have a much larger Ubuntu partition

Good luck.

Comment: It is necessary to enter into a live environment to do this? I do not have a installation media right now, there is no other way to do it?

Comment: Yes, there is another way but it’s a bit complicated.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1251729/20-04-booting-iso-from-grub-menu.  I’ve got this working on my systems. In principle you place the GParted live environment iso on your hard drive and add information to boot it to your grub configuration. This might help too. https://gparted.org/livehd.php

Comment: I've added my own question and answer which describes how I've been able to run a live environment without a usb/cd. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1314402/how-to-modify-partitions-without-a-live-usb-cd . Hope it helps

Comment: thanks a lot for the help

Comment: actualy it is was a little difficult to do in my pc as I my home directory is the one which I want to expand. Though I have tried another thing (which might be stupid), which half complete, see if you can help me in this. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1314596/allocating-space-to-different-disk