# Allocating space to different disk

Tags: disk

Basically I went to Gparted and I unounted OS drive.
[image]

The unallocated space that you can see, I moved it to the Left of the disk **/dev/nvme0n1p2** 23GB. Obviously I cannot unmount this disk so that I can move it to the left end of the unallocated space and allocate  it to the ubuntu drive.

Comment: I wouldn’t make those changes with GParted if I were you. The consensus of opinion on here is use Windows tools for Windows partitions.You can change Windows partitions with Windows disk manager on a running system

Comment: I don't use windows

Comment: Why have you got an ntfs format partition then?

Comment: We cannot have ntfs format partition if we do not use windows? I didn't know that, though I have been storing files in that partition while I was using Ubuntu.

Comment: ntfs will work with Linux but it’s not designed for Linux. You will not get the normal file permission functionality. It’s fine to store data and people do use it to share data between Linux and Windows in a dual boot setup. If you do reduce the size of the ntfs partition to the extent shown on your screenshot you may have issues accessing what’s there. Leave a few GB to work with.

Comment: okay got it, thanks