# Unable to boot from Ubuntu 20.04.02 live usb

Tags: uefi, live-usb

I have Dell XPS 9500 and I am unable to boot from live-usb created via Rufus (or via regular `7z x` ) whatever partition option I choose (MBR/GPT) neither disabling secure boot seem to work. I have an older Manjaro image which works just fine with secure boot turned off. Could you think about any solution to replace existing Manjaro installation with Ubuntu? Thanks.

Comment: When you attempt to boot the live-usb, does it just straight-up not show up in the boot options? Can you describe what happens when attempting to boot the live-usb? Any error messages?

Comment: When I try to boot form UEFI SD explicitly it says something like "no boot device found". If I put UEFI SD up in the hierarchy, it is skipped on boot.

Comment: additionally, you said that you moved it up in the hierachy, but normally I would just change the boot device when booting by pressing "F2" (might be different for you) and then just picking the USB/CD player. Can you try that?

Comment: You need to use UEFI/gpt option in Rufus, not BIOS (CSM) and only boot in UEFI mode. With nVidia. If dual booting with Windows. Windows AHCI driver install:
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-with-intel-r-rst-enabled/15347 & How to Install Ubuntu Linux on your Dell PC 
https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln151664/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-on-your-dell-pc?lang=en

Comment: I've changes the storage mode to Sata when I've installed Manjaro in the first place. Image is burned with GPT + DD option. Updated BIOS to the latest version, nothing seems to help. The system won't boot from livesd card to start the installation.

Comment: Do you have an UEFI setting for allowing USB boot or full USB support? Is UEFI Secure Boot off, that should not be required, but often makes it easier to install, especially if you need proprietary drivers like the nVidia driver to be installed as part of install or first boot after install.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have tried tenths of times with secure boot on and off, tried pointing to the bootx64.efi file manually, tried Ubuntu server, Kubuntu, Mint. Nothing boots besides the older Manjaro image.

Comment: If Manjaro boots using GRUB2 you can add the Ubuntu ISO to the boot menu. For general procedure see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1251729/20-04-booting-iso-from-grub-menu/1251782#1251782  If you need a more detailed answer let me know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot) and [Bootable USB of Ubuntu Minimal CD](https://askubuntu.com/q/689258/)

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend [Universal USB
Installer](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) instead of Rufus.

I had the same issue with my personal computer, tested many solutions that didn't work, and finally that software solved it.

EDIT: I don't recommend to use Universal USB Installer anymore, here is the reason: [USB flash installation medium](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/USB_flash_installation_medium#Inadvisable_methods)

Comment: Image created by UUI are not even recognized as potentially bootable in bios. They just not on the list.

Comment: There is a workaround in the [UUI's FAQ](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/#Troubleshooting), it's the second question, recommending to use a software called [BOOTICE](http://bbs.wuyou.net/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=57675&extra=page%3D1&page=1) to format your Flash Drive as USB-ZIP or USB-HDD, and then use UUI to put your choosen distro on USB. Now, the site recommended to download BOOTICE, is a little confusing, I can't get it the software from there, but here is an alternative: [64 Bits](https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/bootice_64_bit.html).

Comment: Here is a tutorial for BOOTICE: [How to format pendrive or sdcard with BOOTICE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D8BtKk8NAko)