# How to install Ubuntu 20.04 from USB?

Tags: usb-drive

I have a computer Gigabyte z170x Gaming 5. It worked under Windows 11 but now I want to install Ubuntu Desktop 20.04.
What I have made:
On other Ubuntu I have downloaded Ubuntu20.04.iso, formatted USB stick (16GB, FAT32), then copied the iso to this USB

```
ddrescue ubuntu-20.04.6-desktop-amd64.iso /dev/sdb1 --force -D
```

**> GNU ddrescue 1.23 Press Ctrl-C to interrupt

> ```
>  ipos:    4351 MB, non-trimmed:        0 B,  current rate:   1708 kB/s
>  opos:    4351 MB, non-scraped:        0 B,  average rate:   5083 kB/s non-tried:        0 B,  bad-sector:        0 B,    error rate:
> ```
>
> 0 B/s   rescued:    4351 MB,   bad areas:        0,        run time:
> 14m 15s pct rescued:  100.00%, read errors:        0,  remaining time:
> n/a
> time since last successful read:         n/a Finished
> ---------**
>
> Ok, then inserted USB to computer , turn on it, pressed F12: selected
> boot device and received:
> ------- GRUB Loading Welcome to GRUB! Error: unknown file system Entering rescue mode grub rescue>
> -------- What I have made incorrect? Is it possible to boot and install Ubuntu from USB? Thanx.

Comment: What exactly led you to believe that ddrescue was the appropriate tool to create the install media from the .iso file?

Comment: I have found it and used. What is the better tool?

Comment: You wrote it to a partition (*sdb1*)... thus I wouldn't expect it to be bootable unless you've created something to *chainload* to it...  Normally ISOs get written to a device (ie. if you re-format it as you're doing, you need to make it bootable; which can vary by release don't forget!)

Comment: Why not 22.04 which I am now using on my z170?  Another alternative is to extract the ISO into the FAT32 partition  with p7zip. It used to work, then it stopped working with some versions, and does work with most recent. No need to format if using any dd based tool as that just overwrites everything. UEFI only USB key, just extract ISO ( 7 zip or similar) to FAT32 formated flash & set boot flag.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media & 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/v7#Making_a_USB_drive_to_install_Windows

Comment: @user535733 no, it did not help

Comment: @oldfred I agreed, but I need to install and test MS SQL  Server 2022 and it can be installed on 20.04 (thanx to MS).

Comment: I have a HDD & NVMe drive with several installs on each, some now obsolete. I like to keep current LTS as main working install, and test the 6 month releases. Because I am installing a lot, I have ISO on HDD and use grub to loopmount for install to NVMe. Or on NVMe to install to HDD. I used to use flash drives, but internal drive a lot faster. Also tried external SSD & it was almost as fast as internal drive.https://askubuntu.com/questions/1251729/20-04-booting-iso-from-grub-menu/1251782#1251782