How can I install Ubuntu Dual boot (Ubuntu&Win10_64bit)?
I use Win10_64bit on PC. I want to install Ubuntu_Desktop_24.04_LTS dual boot. I made ISO USB-HDD with Rufus_4.5. Than I booted the PC vi USB-HDD. Under bios screen there is "GRUB" only. I can't write anything on screen by keyboard. Screen is freezed. I tried different options of the Rufus but not successfull.
Could you please help me on this issue?

What video card/chip? Some require you to use Safe Boot option and then be sure during install to choose the optional restricted extra drivers. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview

Video card is onboard, Intel(R) 82945G Express Chipset Family (WDDM 1.0). Cpu is Intel Core 2 Duo 3,16Ghz 6MB Cache, Ram is KingSton DDR2 667Mhz 4GB(Usable 3GB), Harddisk Sata Maxtor160GB, Second HD is IDE Samsung 80GB. Motherboard is gigabyte ga-945gcm-s2l, USB-HDD is 320GB for UBUNTU ISO installation.

With those specs you probably are better off with a lighter weight flavor. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie
Flavors of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors)
I like Kubuntu which I use for Desktop, newer laptop and has worked reasonably well with external SSD on 2006 laptop with Core2 Duo and only 1.5GB of RAM.

Thanks. I am downloading Kubuntu now. I use USB-HDD (Western Digital 320GB) for ISO file. Is this the main reason for not to boot with USB-HDD. I tried each optiion of the Rufus. I tried the BalenaEtcher to make ISO on USB-HDD but not succesful.

Writing the ISO file to a drive, normally erases the entire drive as it overwrites the drive's partition table with a DVD/flash drive configuration. If UEFI system, you can create a 6GB or so FAT32 partition with boot,esp flags & just extract ISO into that. That will boot in UEFI mode only has you have not used a tool to create a bootable USB flash drive that works in both UEFI & old BIOS mode.

Is there anybody who install Ubuntu with exteranal USB-HDD(WD-320GB) not memory-stick or flash-memory?

I have not used a flash drive for years. But I use grub to loopmount ISO directly. Since drives are larger I have full install & then a folder with ISOs for grub to boot. I did this years ago, but for newer users Ventoy may be easier. ISO boot: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1251729/20-04-booting-iso-from-grub-menu/1251782#1251782 Ventoy: https://www.ventoy.net/en/doc_grub2boot.html & Extract: http://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media

I make Ubuntu boot USB-HDD(WD-320GB) with Rufus_4.5 with option DD not ISO to install on Desktop PC(with old bios). When I use ISO option on Rufus the old bios not see the USB-HDD. I tried with BalenaEtcher but not succesful it gives an error when loading the file. Now I have dual boot on my PC Ubuntu and Windows11.
