# Unable to boot Gparted Live using grml-rescueboot

Tags: boot, grub2, iso

I installed `grml-rescueboot`, placed Gparted iso file into `/boot/grml` then ran `grub-update`. Now there is a corresponding menu item in GRUB but choosing it does nothing i.e. the GRUB menu comes back instantly. What can be the problem?

Comment: I was able to reproduce the problem.