# How can I manually add a grub2 menu entry to boot from an iso file?

Tags: boot, grub2, 22.04, iso

I am attempting to install from a iso and I want to try to add an menu entry in grub that I can boot from. I want to keep the current OS I have but install this one alongside it. I know very very little so I need a lot of assistance.

Edit: This provides much info [How do I boot an ISO file from my drive using grub2 on UEFI machines?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025656/how-do-i-boot-an-iso-file-from-my-drive-using-grub2-on-uefi-machines)

Also check the Grub2 Documentation for examples: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot

Comment: @guiverc Exactly what I was looking for. You saved me a lot of time.