# Upgrade to 12.04

Tags: 12.04

After I upgrade,do I again need to configure wireless and Bluetooth?all the installed Software will be there or again I have to download and install?

Comment: Nope! It's simply there already (So long as you do it properly via the builtin command/gui)

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading your existing system will generally keep all your drivers, applications, files and settings. If you do a clean install, then you will need to re-install everything.

Answer (score 0):

You should always backup your data before upgrading your Ubuntu operating system. You can also [backup the whole system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19901/how-to-make-a-disk-image-and-restore-from-it-later) depending on what is important to you.

A [correct upgrading](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TrustyUpgrades) will keep however your other settings as they are.

I think these [answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu) will be helpful for you to read them before upgrading.