# How to Copy my entire Ubuntu OS into new laptop for installing along with all data and programs installed

Tags: 14.04, backup

What I require is to make an exact copy of my existing Ubuntu installation along with all data and applications into a new laptop. What are the simple method's for a normal computer user without much complicated steps.

Comment: Why not simply move hard drive into the new laptop ? Personally that's what I did. My laptop is Toshiba C55, with UEFI , so i had to disable secure boot option and switch to bios compatability mode, but if your laptop just uses bios - go ahead and plug in the hdd right away

Comment: @Serg Yea I know thats an option, but I need an alternative not like moving HDD :)

Comment: One option could be: create a backup disk image, move it to your new system and restore from it. Several ways to create a disk image is discussed in http://askubuntu.com/questions/19901/how-to-make-a-disk-image-and-restore-from-it-later

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Clonezilla Live](http://clonezilla.org/):

Two types of Clonezilla are available, Clonezilla live and Clonezilla SE (server edition). **Clonezilla live** is suitable for single machine backup and restore

OR

**Systemback Tool**

The Systemback tool allows you to create restore points, backups, and live images of a running system. Currently, it only works for Ubuntu derivatives based on 14.04, 14.10, and 15.04.

https://launchpad.net/systemback

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:nemh/systemback

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install systemback
```