# Intalling ubuntu16.10 on a pen drive

Tags: 16.10

I have downloaded Ubuntu 16.10 iso on my hard disk. I want to install the same on a formatted Pen Drive, as a back up copy

Comment: Downloaded and installed are two different things. Do you mean you have installed ubuntu on your hard drive and wish to install ubuntu on your pen drive? If you simply want to copy the iso file to the pen drive then just use some file manager to do that. If you want to install ubuntu then you will need to boot into ubuntu and then run the installer and point it to your pen drive during the installation process. See this guide [https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this question has previously been asked and also answered. Please follow [Backup direction here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19901/how-to-make-a-disk-image-and-restore-from-it-later) for a few different options.

There are two GUI solutions. If you want to brave the commandline to do this, then I'd recommend `gddrescue` rather than `dd`. Do not confuse it with ddrescue.  Here's how to install it if you choose:

```
sudo apt-get install gddrescue
man gddrescue
```

The man page will give you an explanation, though I suspect you're looking for a simple GUI tool like the link provideds.