# Clone the physical Ubuntu to image

Tags: server

First to duplicate the physical Ubuntu first and then restore to another physical Ubuntu server

Comment: @muru: OP changed their question and wants to clone to a physical machine now.

Comment: Or http://askubuntu.com/q/19901/158442. Still a dupe, so I'm not retracting my CV