# Flashing Ubuntu ISO to USB stick with dd: recommended block size

Tags: usb-drive, dd

What is a reasonable `bs` to use when running `dd` to flash an Ubuntu image? I am using:

```bash
dd if=ubuntu-17.04-server-amd64.iso of=/dev/sda bs=1M
```

The `ubuntu-17.04-server-amd64.iso` file is 685 M.

I am running this dd operation on a strong server, with `bs=1M`. It takes almost 3 minutes (154 seconds):

```
718274560 bytes (718 MB) copied, 154.192 s, 4.7 MB/s
```

I assume that if I will use a higher `bs`, like `bs=500M`, it will be quicker (though I did not check it).

What is a recommended and reliable `bs=` for such dd command?

Comment: Typically its done with 4M , see https://askubuntu.com/q/372607/295286

Answer (score 20):

### My standard `dd` block size is `bs=4096`

Some years ago I tested different block sizes, and found that **`bs=4096`** is a good value for most cases. It made no big difference to increase the block size to higher values. If I understood correctly, it was also the value used by several programs (cat, cp etc). This is the block size used for `dd` under the hood in **[mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)**.

Things may have changed since I tested different block sizes, but I think the speed in your case is limited by the flash memory hardware. A fast USB 3 pendrive or fast memory card will be 5 times faster (~25 MB/s) even when connected via USB 2. See this link and links from it,

[help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Notes_about_speed](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Notes_about_speed)

So you can continue with `bs=1M` or use `bs=4096`.

If you wish, you can try some different block sizes, but do not expect any big improvement. Please come back and report the result, particularly if you find a major improvement. In that case it is also important to specify the hardware and the operating system (version of Ubuntu).

### Edit: New test

I tested again, with current Lubuntu 16.04 LTS versions, and computer hardware of different kind and age, as described in the following table and graphs.

**Test details**

- The test was run with a shell-script, that for each block size *wiped and synced* the first Gibibyte of the target USB pendrive (overwrote with zeros), *then cloned and synced* from a Lubuntu iso file (which is slightly smaller than one Gibibyte, so within the wiped part of the pendrive).
- In all cases a pure `dd` command line was used (no piping via `pv` or similar commands).
- Most tests were run from Lubuntu 16.04.2 LTS amd64 system (with a yakkety kernel) installed in an SSD, but the tests in an HP xw8400 workstation were run with the installed Lubuntu 16.04 LTS i386 system (with a xenial kernel) in an internal HDD.
- 'Extreme' and 'Cruzer_blade' are Sandisk USB pendrive models
- 'drive port' is where the target USB pendrive is connected
- 'os port' is where the SSD or HDD with the operating system is connected
- More details are listed in the following table, and the variations due to the block size are illustrated in the following graphs with `log (block size)` along the x-axis because of the character of the range of block size values,

  - 512 (default)
  - 4096 (4K)
  - 65536 (64K)
  - 1048576 (1M)
  - 4194304 (4M)

[image: dd-blocksize-test-table]

[image: dd-blocksize-test-graphs]

**Conclusions**

- The default block size, `bs=512` (bytes) makes `dd` slow.
- Cloning with block sizes from `bs=4096 to 4M` run at 'full speed'. There are only minor differences between the test cases (except for `bs=512`).

Comment: Wow, that is a very extensive test! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using a usb stick that is USB 3.x compatible, I get 65MB/s for an ISO burn.

```
sudo dd if=xubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=4M
405+1 records in
405+1 records out
1699577856 bytes (1.7 GB, 1.6 GiB) copied, 26.4146 s, 64.3 MB/s
```