# How to make a complete removal of Python 3.9 in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, python3

I installed Python 3.9 on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS system, in addition to the default 2.7 and 3.5 that come with the system. I can call it perfectly by typing python3.9, and also use pip3.9 commands.

I want to remove it form the system, for reinstalling it, or even and earlier version of python instead.

I tried already `sudo apt-get remove python3.9` , `sudo apt-get autoremove python3.9`, `sudo apt-get purge python3.9`, `sudo apt-get remove --purge python3.9` and `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge python3.9`. None seems to make effect.

When I call `python3.9` it comes:

```
Python 3.9.0 (default, Nov 14 2020, 00:35:31)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

How could I fix that?  Thx

Answer (score 14, accepted):

in case you still need it.

first of all, it's never advisable to uninstall python. check for instance this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/911448/uninstall-python-3-6).
having said this, Ubuntu 16.04 does not depend (wasn't build) on Python 3.9 (check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232812/whats-the-default-python-version-in-ubuntu-20-04) out, for instance). thus, and in principle you shouldn't be having problems fully uninstalling it... as it was my case.

i had no troubles following [these](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/08/5-ways-free-up-space-on-ubuntu) steps; which for you/me would be something like:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
sudo apt-get remove python3.9
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

good luck!

Comment: Need more than "not working" to help you. Error messages, things you expect that aren't happening, or vice versa, etc.

Comment: Hey your answer has helped me as well. but do you think its advisable to maybe consider upgrading my ubuntu 16 to say ubuntu 20? I have been using ubuntu 16 from around 2017 and after trying other versions like 17 and 18, i just decided to resort to my 16 because it was just stabler for me. but these days i get a lot of version conflicts with a lot of the software i always want to install. some advice.

Comment: hi @N.M.Jedidiah. this is more of a cautionary tale. rule #1: **IF IT AIN'T BROKEN, DON'T TRY FIX IT** :D. I upgraded to Ubuntu 20LTS, and it's awesome. i was on Ubuntu 18. *long story short:* i ended up installing U20 from scratch cause my machine broke during the upgrading. So, 1st of all back up your files!!. then, do something [like this](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-to-20-04-lts-focal-fossa). If you ended up having [this issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/448926/how-to-fix-python-installation-is-corrupted) you'll be as miserable as i was; but **if you never try...**

Answer (score 2):

1. Install synaptic using

   ```
   sudo apt install synaptic
   ```
2. Open synaptic

   [image: enter image here]
3. Search for "python 3.9"

   [image: enter image here]
4. Right click on "python 3.9" and Select "mark for complete removal"

   [image: enter image here]
5. Click apply

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu 20.04.2 I had a similar issue and following these steps the python dependency was fixed

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
sudo apt-get remove python3.9
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

Comment: Ubuntu 20 is built on python3.9, removing python3.9 may cause side effects.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 is based on python3.8, removing python3.9 should therefore be safe.