# What are the main differences between a system snapshots (Timeshift) and partition images (saved as iso)?

Tags: backup, rsync, btrfs, disk-image, snapshot

Following comments under [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/589060/47206) answer of mine I became interested in the question whether the best option for me in order to back-up a system is a partition back-up as described at the linked answer or a snapshot as created by Timeshift (which I have not yet used).

So, I know what a partition image is and how it can be created and restored, but I would like to know whether snapshots are a better option or not. I have some info about snapshots but I want to know more details on the differences between snapshots and partition isos as far as restoration is concerned.

I see that there are differences between the two types of snapshots created by  Timeshift as they are clearly listed once the program starts.

[image]

[image]

As my system is on an ext4 partition (and I find preferable to save the snapshot on an external drive), the option that I will use for now is RSYNC. But I am interested about BTRFS, which I plan to use in the future.

---

The clarifications I need regard mainly the following aspects:

Do I have to **run the very system that I have backed-up** with Timeshift in order to restore the snapshot?

It seems to me that's the case, contrary to a partition saved as iso. In that case the system that I have just backed-up has to be functional and Timeshift installed in it in order to restore the back-up. But then what is the point of that back-up? Normally I want a back-up in case I lose the backed-up system. **If the OS is lost, how can the snapshot be restored?**

My idea of a back-up is to save a healthy well customized system that I could restore later when the running system has become bloated or unusable.

It seems to me that the purpose of a snapshot is to constantly make back-ups of the actual running system in its present state. But if the system is not in good health are these back-ups efficient? Or are the snapshots images of various stages/moments of the system that are ALL saved, including an initial, healthy and well-customized one? Even so, how is that to be restored if the running system is lost?

Or maybe I'm wrong and Snapshot can restore a system B onto a system A, thus replacing it?

Comment: Why do you think that you "have to run the very system that I have backed-up with Timeshift in order to restore the snapshot". That is clearly not the case. You can restore from a live usb.

Comment: @RoVo - I was asking whether that's the case. I had heard about restoring from a live usb but I don't understand how that works, I haven't found details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Do I have to run the very system that I have backed-up with Timeshift in order to restore the snapshot?

That is clearly not the case:

> ● Snapshots can be restored either from the running system (online restore) or **from a live CD (offline restore)**.

---

### If the OS is lost, how can the snapshot be restored?

> ● An offline restore is when you restore a system other than the one that you are currently running. If you have a multi-boot setup, then you can boot into one installed OS and then restore another OS that may be installed on another disk. You can also boot from a Linux Live CD or USB, install Timeshift and then restore the installed system. An offline restore using a Live CD/USB may be required if your installed system is not bootable.
>
> ● The snapshots to be restored can be of any Linux distribution. [...] Timeshift will take care of things like reinstalling the bootloader and other details.

---

[Read the docs](https://github.com/teejee2008/timeshift/wiki/Restoring-Snapshots) for more information.

---

### Benefits of using Timeshift (rsync) compared to cloning your disk:

- Only first backup is a full backup, the following backups are incremental.

  - saves a lot of disk space
  - backing up is much faster
  - You can restore your system to any point in time you have backups for
- Thimeshift will not backup unused space.
- On restore, you can choose whether to restore the bootlader or not.
- On restore, you can choose which files to keep and which files to restore.

### Benefits of cloning your disk compared to Timeshift (rsync):

- Doesn't need to be stored on a Linux File System.
- Use standard Linux tool to restore.

### Benefits of using Timeshift (BTRFS):

- Backup happens on File System level using file system features only.
- Initial backup is fast and doesn't use any space
- Backup on the same disk, no additional disks needed

but ...

- Needs BTRFS with special layout on the system
- Backup on the same disk means data loss if disk is broken.

Comment: Great. I only need a "perfect" saved form of my system that I could restore later, I don't need constant snapshots because I don't need the last form of my system but an initial one. In this respect snapshots are similar to saved partitions without the difficulties. - Your answer clarifies the most important aspects, but my question was intended for a more general comparison between images and snapshots. For example: given that snapshots have the aforementioned advantages: are there any theoretical pros of saving system partition images instead of system snapshots?

Comment: I will expand my answer.

Comment: one advantage of iso images is that they can be easily saved on any support, while snapshots require certain file-systems. I have a lot of external drives all ntfs-formatted, none are suited as such for timeshift. on the other hand iso images of partitions are more difficult to create and especially to restore, and they *require* the deletion of the previous system, whether that's what I want or not