# Reinstalling Xubuntu without losing data

Tags: xubuntu

I need to reinstall Xubuntu on a new, bigger hard drive (I can't find a way to increase the partition size, but that's a separate question). How would I go about doing this without losing data, software installed, preferences, etc.

Thanks,
djtravz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're upgrading your xubuntu installation to a larger HDD, and wish to keep the same configuration and apps, use `Clonezilla` to clone the current small HDD to the larger HDD, then use `gparted` to resize your partitions to accommodate the extra unallocated space on the larger HDD.

https://clonezilla.org/

Here's a partial template that I use when instructing users how to use `gparted` to edit the partitions. A gparted screenshot of the current disk structure would be required to complete the individual steps...

---

## Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or loose data.

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a `swapoff` on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a `swapon` on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower pane of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted`
- more to come...

Answer (score 1):

If you want the system software programs that you might've modified (eg: apt sources)

1. You could make a `dd` Image of your current HDD (not
   recommended)  ([Tutorial on how to create dd image](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-dd-create-make-disk-image-commands/))
2. You could use `clonezilla` ([Tutorial on how to clonezilla](https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/free_imaging_software.html))
3. [And here is a similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19901/how-to-make-a-disk-image-and-restore-from-it-later)