# Expanded Ubuntu partition size, now loads into grub

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning

I ran out of space on my Ubuntu 16.04 partition so I used easeUS partition master on Windows 10 to shrink my Windows partition, move the unallocated space over, then expand the Ubuntu partition. Now when I try to boot into Ubuntu, I only get the grub terminal.

I was able to locate the grub.cfg file but after trying to set it as the config file, I got a very quick error message containing a bunch of seemingly random numbers and letters.

> error: no such device: 7debd206-c...

I was also unable to find the vmlinuz file.

When using the "set" command I get back:

```
?=0
cmdpath=(hdq,gpt2)/EFI/ubuntu
...
lang =
locale_dir=
net_default_ip=(null)
net_default_mac=(null)
net_default_server=
pager=
pxe_default_server=
root=hd1,gpt2
secondary_locale_dir=
```

Where the "..." are settings what I assume to be unnecessary for this question.

Booting ubuntu off a flashdrive I am able to list the partitions on my computer and the one that should be the Ubuntu partition says Microsoft basic data. I dont think this is important but I thought it would be better to include it anyway.

If anyone can help me boot up Ubuntu without having to format the partition that would be great! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EaseUS only supports `EXT2` and `EXT3` partitions.**

So if you used `EXT4` (the default in 16.04) it indeed converted it to a Windows Basic Partition.

The only thing left to you to do is (in increasing order of difficultly)

- Restore your [System Backip](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19901/how-to-make-a-disk-image-and-restore-from-it-later)
- Reinstall from scratch and restore your [data backup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools)
- Use [Testdisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step) to recover your partition
- Use [PhotoRec](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) to recover individual files.

Comment: This is very helpful, Ill try these and let you know if they work. Thanks!

Comment: Please don't use EaseUS: Use `gparted` instead.