# Error fixing grub after resizing partition (grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory)

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, gparted

I had a dual boot system and removed the Windows partition using Gparted by booting from a USB. After this, I was not able to boot into the Ubuntu system (or even get to the grub menu). Gparted had warned this could happen, so I am following the instructions [here](https://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual&lang=C#gparted-fix-grub-boot-problem) (the *Restoring GRUB 2 Boot Loader* section). When I get to step 8 the grub-install command fails.

Here is everything I have typed into the terminal to get to that point

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mkdir /tmp/mydir
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p6 /tmp/mydir
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount --bind /dev /tmp/mydir/dev
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount --bind /proc /tmp/mydir/proc
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount --bind /sys /tmp/mydir/sys
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo chroot /tmp/mydir
root@ubuntu:/# sudo grub-install /dev/nvme0n1p
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory.
```

Here is a screenshot of Gparted post-resizing.

[image]

Any help resolving this issue so I can boot into my system would be much appreciated!

Comment: In addition to Fabby's answer: You used instructions to reinstall BIOS version of Grub. If you reinstall EFI version of Grub, you have to mount the ESP as well, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/831216/how-can-i-reinstall-grub-to-the-efi-partition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that the EFI partition was converted from FAT to NTFS.

The possibilities are (in increasing order of complexity)

- Restore your last full [System Backup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19901/how-to-make-a-disk-image-and-restore-from-it-later)
- Reinstall from scratch and restore your [data backup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools)
- Boot an Ubuntu Live USB and:

  - Mount `nvme0n1p1`
  - copy all files off it in a secure location (*hell: copy them twice!*)
  - delete `nvme0n1p1` using `gparted`
  - recreate it with the same size in `FAT16` or `FAT32` format (`gparted` again)
  - give it `boot` and `esp` flags. (`gparted`)
  - copy all files back from the secure location
  - reboot