# Upgrading a 16.04 server to 18.04 with a secondary fully encrypted drive

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, upgrade, encryption

As per the upgrade notes:

> N.B., If you require multipath, **full-disk encryption**, or the ability to re-using existing partitions, you will want to continue to use the alternate installer which can be downloaded from http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04/release/ As of 18.04.1, the Subiquity server installer now supports LVM, RAID, vlans, and bonds.

I have an existing ubuntu server 16.04. It has 2 hard drives. The boot and OS are on the first without encryption. It also has an encrypted storage drive that I manually mount.

My command line is offering to upgrade to 18.04 and I wouldn't mind just for the PHP 7.2 support (might bump that to 7.3). However the patch notes have me a bit worried. Would I still be able to manually mount my fully encrypted drive if I ran "do-release-upgrade'?

It also said I cannot reuse existing partitions. If I cannot use existing partitions what does it do to them? Merge them? Remake them?

I am just trying to get a good idea of what to expect when upgrading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Full Disk Encryption** in this case means *including `/boot/`* so if you manually mount the secondary encrypted disk, you can leave it unmounted while performing the upgrade.

As you don't mention any details about the contents nor the specific encryption used of the secondary drive, the old adagio still stands:

#### Make a full [System Backup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19901/how-to-make-a-disk-image-and-restore-from-it-later) before starting! ;-)

Comment: Just like to say, to future searchers, I did the update from command line and everything went perfectly besides some error related to full disk encryption which I am not using.

Comment: Thank you for the textual feed-back and the acceptance!  Favour returned, question upvoted!  **:-)**