# Creating a disk image while a disk is mounted

Tags: backup

I was looking over this [AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19901/how-to-make-a-disk-image-and-restore-from-it-later) and don't feel that the OP's question fully answered. Is there a disk imaging utility for Ubuntu that allows the OS to be imaged while it is mounted, like Acronis or Macrium Reflect?

I'd like to be able to schedule disk images to run every so often, and that isn't really an option if I have to boot from a live CD/USB to make an image each time.

Comment: I think you are asking the wrong question. A better question would be "What *filesystems* are capable of snapshots and full-disk backups without unmounting?" (Hint: Both ZFS and BTRFS)

Comment: @user535733 Is there a good resource that lists the various Linux file systems and their capabilities?

I see that there's now an option for Ubuntu to use ZFS instead of EXT4 during the initial installation. If I were to reinstall the OS using the ZFS file system, how would I go about making a disk image?

Comment: Good resource: Wikipedia. After reading about the filesystems available, step back from the firm idea of a "disk image" and think about the other backup concepts offered. Migrating a set of complex concepts from one OS onto a very different OS requires some flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

The Unix tool for this task is `dd`, which is described in the linked question. This can be scheduled using crontab or similar, and does not require booting from a live USB or CD.

Comment: Does dd run a risk of data corruption if files change while the command is in progress?