# What would I lose from my system if I do a clean reinstall of Ubuntu and restore my Home partition?

Tags: home-directory, re-installation

Sorry if this question is too open-ended.

I would like to know what I would lose from my system if I decided to do a clean re-install of Ubuntu. I have a separate Home partition so after restoring that what we have been removed?

All applications I have installed?
Firefox add-ons?
I had to make a change to /etc/rc.local to fix Wifi, will that need doing again?

Thanks for any help, sorry if the answer is a massive list of potential things, I just don't know that's why I'm asking! Perhaps it would make more sense to ask, "What is saved in my home partition?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will lose everything that was not on your home partition :-)

You already mentioned or need to think of:

- changes to `/etc/rc.local` and `/etc/` in general
- changes to the software sources you used (`/etc/apt`)
- all software you have installed (you can save a list of the installed software via the software-center and reinstall later, but you have to think of it...)
- software installed outside the debian system (by typing `make; make install`, `easy_install`, `cpan`, `ctan`, ...), those often live in `/opt/...`
- probably a lot I can't think of at the moment...

You will not lose most of the configuration, as this is often saved under `~/.conf`.

For answers on how to backup all your system components you can have a look at this question: [How to backup settings and list of installed packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9135/best-way-to-backup-all-settings-list-of-installed-packages-tweaks-etc) and [Easy backup/restore of installed system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13278/easy-backup-restore-of-installed-system)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a separate /home partition then you will lose nothing, on a fresh install of Ubuntu on the / partition (making sure you dont format /home during install) all of your current files and even preferences and bookmarks will remain in tact...