# Grub failure after upgrading to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, 11.10, grub2, upgrade

I have a computer with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 11.04.

While updating from 11.04 to 12.04 an error occurred with `grub`. It would load but wouldn't let me launch any of the Operating Systems. I had to reinstall 11.04 to have `grub` working as before.

I would like to know if upgrading from Internet from within Ubuntu, or if installing from CD, the same error will occur. I cannot lose the Windows 7 partition.

There is no support for 11.04 any longer, so I would like to upgrade.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Este sitio funciona solamente en inglés, así que por favor usá ese idioma. Si no sabés inglés, podés hacer una traducción en internet y poner en tu pregunta tanto el texto original como la traducción automática. Todas las respuestas estarán en inglés invariablemente. -- The language of this site is English, so please use that language. If don't know any English, use an internet-based translator and put both original and automatically translated text. All answers will invariably be in English.

Answer (score 0):

Check the answers given in [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/q/34430/58950).

You'd have to upgrade 11.04 to 11.10, and *only then* upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04.

[Back up your system](https://askubuntu.com/q/19901/58950) (see also [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/13278/58950)), back up your personal files and configurations (located at the `~/home` folder) and proceed with the two-step upgrade.

Alternatively, after backing-up your files, make a clean install of 12.04. Note that if you make a clean install, you'll have to reinstall any additinal software you might have installed besides of the default ones.