# Best backup software for ubuntu

Tags: backup

I need a backup software for Ubuntu 14.04 that has a GUI that can backup my entire system to an external hard drive or network drive. Any recommendations?

Comment: Do you want to backup your *system* files? In that case you can take a look at the Ubuntu Software Center option to «Sync between computers» For your personal files and config you can use Dejâ Dup

Answer (score 0):

For backing up installed Softwares, preferences, themes & sources, go for Aptik

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install aptik
```

& for entire system backup refer to this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13278/easy-backup-restore-of-installed-system).

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest `rsync`, a built in package, but it doesn't have GUI.

You can go ahead with Clonezilla, that's what I prefer.