# ubuntu full backup

Tags: backup, root, system, restore

I'm using ubuntu 18.04 on my asus rog gl502vm laptop.
After installation I've installed many applications and updates and done a ton of configuration. Now I wanna get a backup of the current stable state of ubuntu so when I install it again I don't have to go through so much steps to get to this very state. How can I backup root and home partitions in a way that it'd be restorable to my future ubuntus?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easy backup/restore of installed system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13278/easy-backup-restore-of-installed-system)

Comment: Hello Mahdi, welcome to the forum. This is a good question, but it has [already been asked](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13278/easy-backup-restore-of-installed-system) several times.  There's also a [community wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem) you can refer to. Please read the [How-to-ask](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) guide to ensure your questions are in accordance with the acceptable standards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparison of backup tools](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools)

Comment: @Dawoodjee To be accurate, this is [not a forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92107/217657).

Answer (score 0):

I spent a month looking into this a while back, I ended up using timeshift, I was easily able to backup my entire 10 year old AMD server and install it onto a virtual drive on my new dual Xeon setup, when done it has worked perfect every since I only needed to change my Network card settings to what the other machine was so I have the same IP address. I only backup with Timeshift now for all my machines! The funny thing is mostly what I see on the internet says timeshift can't do it. It only uses the space needed also, (instead of having to partition another drive to the exact same size, then boot up a disc to clone your drive) with Timeshift I only recommend that you stop your MySql server while it backs up so you get a consistent backup. The backup size is small and the first one takes the longest ( about 25 min for 200GB ), after that it does snapshots (differences) in a way that you can restore the whole system from any snapshot, you can also delete if you get too many, you can also automate everything, it is almost too easy to use, here is the resource I originally found - https://www.everything-linux-101.com/blog/install-timeshift-in-ubuntu-18-04/